# How do I make postgres user as the main user instead of typing psql -U postgres?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I install my psql 12.4 using this: https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads
When the system prompt me to enter password for user "postgres". I did give it a password.

But when I type psql on powershell terminal, it will require me to give password for user JinTan which i do not have.

```
(base) PS C:\Users\JinTan> psql
Password for user JinTan:
```

The only password i have is this:

```
(base) PS C:\Users\JinTan> psql -U postgres
Password for user postgres:
psql (12.4)
WARNING: Console code page (437) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=#
```

So my question is:
How do I make postgres user as the main user instead of typing psql -U postgres?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-envars.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks, but how should i configure my env?
I have added this to my env path: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin

Comment: Why not just create a database user named "JinTan" to be your main user?  "postgres" is supposed to reserved for maintenance and administrative operations.

Comment: As documented in that link, you need to [create an environment variable](https://www.qwant.com/?q=windows+define+environment+variable) `PGUSER` with the user you want

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks, now I get what you are saying. :)
Do you know how can I disable the password input for user? In other words, when i type psql in power shell, I do not have to type password.

Comment: You can edit [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks all for the advise. I have solved it using all the advise.

I use 'a_horse_with_no_name' method to add PGUSER with value of 'postgres' in my env variable.

To not allow system to ask for password everytime,
I use "Belayer" method to change all of the "md5" value in pg_hba.conf to "trust".

Then it works like charm without needing me to enter password everytime.